# How to solve system of 3 equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to compute $x(1-x)$ in terms of $a,b,$ and $c$, but I am not sure how to approach this problem. I tried doing a lot of manipulation in form of squares making squares of either in $x$, $y$, $z$ or $1-x$, $1-y$, $1-z$, but I was unsuccessful. If possible, a high school way of solving problem will be appreciated. The system of equations is as shown below:

$$\begin{align*}
x^{2} + (1-y)^{2} = a\\
y^{2} + (1-z)^{2} = b\\
z^{2} + (1-x)^{2} = c
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Please do not use pictures. We have $3$ equations, not $14$.

Comment: Please type your question using MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @DietrichBurde hey i cant type those equations from keyboarrd. I am new and learning to use all these.I will take care of these things from now.i have seem the Jax method i will edit it.thanks

Comment: hey, but what you can do is to search on this site. I have seen these equation here already:)

Comment: If you want to learn how to type such equations (and also much more complex ones), have a look at the Math.SE [Math Jax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You can expand each of these out and then use substitution
$$
\begin{align*}
x^{2} = a - (1-y)^{2}\\
y^{2} = b - (1-z)^{2}\\
z^{2} = c - (1-x)^{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Then note that
$$
y^{2} = b - \left(1-\sqrt{c-(1-x)^{2}}\right)^{2}\\
x^{2} = a - \left(1-\sqrt{b - \left(1-\sqrt{c-(1-x)^{2}}\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}
$$

This is a bit of a long-winded way to find $x$, but you can then solve for $x$, and as a result $(1-x)$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$. I imagine there is a simpler way to do this which somebody will hopefully post. However, this is a start.

Comment: it will be helpfull if u solve it further, at this point i am not getting some way to take both vairiable and constants at diff sides.